# The requested resource was not found on this server OR 404 error on server

Tags: php, laravel, apache, server

I am trying to create a filesystem upload for my blog news.

I have this code on my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

          ini_set('memory_limit','99999M');
    ini_set('post_max_size','99999M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize','99999M');
    ini_set('max_input_time', 36000); // 10 houres
    set_time_limit(36000); // 10 houres
    $file= $request->file('image');
    $filename= date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $now = Carbon::now();
        $randomChain = Str::random(12);
        $pic = $randomChain.$file;
        Post::create(['title' => $request->title, 
            'body' => $request->body, 
            'user_id' => Auth::id(), 
            'slug' =>  Str::slug($request->title), 
            'meta_description' =>  Str::substr($request->body,0, 147), 
            'meta_keywords' => $request->body, 
            'excerpt' => Str::substr($request->body,0, 147), 
            'active' => 1, 
            'image' => $filename,
            'created_at' => $now, 
            'updated_at' => NULL, 
            'seo_title' => '',]
        );

        Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  $file);
```

It seems to work fine, data are correctly insered in table, and the file (an image) is uploaded on my localhost server and on production server too. But in the two cases, I can't access on the image via 127.0.0.1:8000/img/image.jpg or server.com/img/image.jpg

It returns to me an erreur from Apache (I guess) "The requested resource was not found on this server" on localhost. And on my server it returns a 404 error. But the file image.jpg is on the 2 servers, I can show it by doing ls -ila and I correctyly type the URL by doing copy and paste.

Also there is the code for the upload view :

```
                     <div class="p-5">
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="titre"><br />
    <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="article"></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Choose image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" name="Envoyer">

</form>
```

And maybe me fylesystem.php can help you :

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),



    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('mvbimg') => storage_path('app/mvbimg'),


    ],

];
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: try `php artisan optimize:clear` and `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Still not working. I edited my original post to add filesystem.php maybe It can help

Comment: because the link folder is storage so you have to use 127.0.0.1:8000/storage/img/image.jpg. see this env('APP_URL').'/storage',